# c# two statements in while

Tags: c#, while-loop

I was writing a program which takes input from the keyboard and prints a square matrix in the following spiral manner

```
1 2 3 
8 9 4 
7 6 5
```

I managed to write the program but I encountered a weird error. 
in line 26 it gives me an index out of bound exception

```
while (matrix[row, col] == 0 && col < matrix.GetLength(0) )
```

However if I switch the order of the two statements inside the loop the exception is gone ? Does this mean that the order of the two statements in the while loop is important ? And if yes , why ? Shouldn't it be if both statements are true to execute the loop, and if one of them is false, no matter which one, to stop executing it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpiralMatrixN
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //prompt the user to enter n
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of n");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] matrix = new int[n,n];
            Console.Clear();
            System.Console.SetWindowSize(100, 30);
            int value = 1;
            int col = 0;
            int row = 0;
            if (n>0 && n<21)
            {
                while(value <= n*n)
                {
                    while (matrix[row, col] == 0 && col < matrix.GetLength(0) )
                    {
                        matrix[row, col++] = value;
                        value++;
                    }
                    col--;
                    row++;
                    while (row < matrix.GetLength(1) && matrix[row, col] == 0)
                    {
                        matrix[row++, col] = value;
                        value++;
                    }

                    row--;
                    col--;
                    while (col >= 0 && matrix[row, col] == 0 )
                    {
                        matrix[row, col--] = value;
                        value++;
                    }
                    col++;
                    row--;
                    while (matrix[row, col] == 0 && row >= 0)
                    {
                        matrix[row--, col] = value;

                        value++;
                    }

                    col++;
                    row++;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(j * 5, i * 2);
                        Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make sure the values of `row` and `col` are what you are expecting them to be.  Put a breakpoint in and make sure the loop is behaving the way you want it to.

Comment: you should post your code here

Comment: Yes, because of short-circuiting. I'm sure there's a nice duplicate somewhere..

Comment: Not related to your question, but you're comparing `col` and `row` to the wrong value. You should have `col < matrix.GetLength(1)` and `row < matrix.GetLength(0)`. It works in your current code because both dimensions are `n`, but if you had a matrix that wasn't square you would run into a problem because of this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, order is important. Conditions in the && clause are executed in the order of precedence, and if one fails another is not executed. Currently what you have fails because `matrix[row, col] == 0` is executed first, and `col` comes out of bounds. So your check for `col` (which is absolutely correct btw) should come first:

```
while (col < matrix.GetLength(0) && matrix[row, col] == 0)
```

If it fails, second statement won't be executed and you won't have an error. This is called "short-circuit evaluation".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is called short circuit evaluation. Since you are using "&&", the second condition gets evaluated only after the first one evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` and `||` operators are known as "<strike>shortcut</strike> short-circuit operators"; the second half is only evaluated if necessary. This is useful for two reasons:

1. It's more efficient during execution since less code is run (not usually *much* more, but if you're doing IO or something it could be), and
2. It's convenient for programming since you can use the first half as a precondition to the second half even being evaluated. Such as,

   `if (myObj != null && myObj.Name == "something")`

   If both halves were evaluated above, you'd get an error from `myObj.Name` whenever myObj was null.

If you do need both halves of the expression evaluated no matter what, you can use the `&` or the `|` operators. I find I rarely do.

[MSDN: && Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The order in && is important && uses short-circuiting vs & which does not.  In an && expression from left to right if a condition is false the other conditions are not evaluated.

> **Conditional logical operators**
>
> The && and || operators are called the conditional logical operators.
>   They are also called the "short-circuiting" logical operators.
>
> conditional-and-expression:
>
> inclusive-or-expression
>    conditional-and-expression   &&   inclusive-or-expression
>
> conditional-or-expression:
>
> conditional-and-expression
>    conditional-or-expression   ||   conditional-and-expression*
>
> - The && and || operators are conditional versions of the & and |
>     operators:
> - The operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y,
>     except that y is evaluated only if x is true.
>
> The operation x || y corresponds to the operation x | y, except that y
>   is evaluated only if x is false.
>
> An operation of the form x && y or x || y is processed by applying
>   overload resolution (Section 7.2.4) as if the operation was written x
>   & y or x | y. Then,
>
> - If overload resolution fails to find a single best
>     operator, or if overload resolution selects one of the predefined
>     integer logical operators, a compile-time error occurs.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is one of the predefined Boolean
>     logical operators (Section 7.10.2), the operation is processed as
>     described in Section 7.11.1.
> - Otherwise, the selected operator is a user-defined operator, and the
>     operation is processed as described in Section 7.11.2.
>
> It is not possible to directly overload the conditional logical operators.
>   However, because the conditional logical operators are evaluated in
>   terms of the regular logical operators, overloads of the regular
>   logical operators are, with certain restrictions, also considered
>   overloads of the conditional logical operators. This is described
>   further in Section 7.11.2.

From [MSDN C# Conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)